# How can I see Firebase Storage Usage in the Console

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

I am using Firebase for almost 2 months now for my app in production and right now I am on Spark plan for sometime until I get user base. I see that the Spark pricing allows 1GB of downloads per day and 5GB of total storage but nowhere on the console I am able to see how much storage quota I have used up  now. This is really important to a lot of users, if you show usage information for Database you should show it for storage as well.

Answer (score 3):

As long as Storage is concerned it's actually a Google Cloud Storage Bucket, you can visit the Google Cloud Console and see the details. Firebase currently does not show the bucket usage details.

You can send them a feature request from this link :

https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/

Comment: I cannot locate the option to check storage. Can you please provide the steps where I can find it.

Answer (score 2):

Like Raghvendra said, you can view it on the Google Cloud Console at the following link: https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser/my-app.appspot.com

`my-app` will be your project name, and is the same as the one you use on Firebase: https://console.firebase.google.com/project/my-app/storage/my-app.appspot.com/files